# How to use previous information when I use "by" in R?

Tags: r, data.table, forex

I have a data from forex market(mydt) saved by data.table:

```
datetime|side(0=Bid,1=Ask)| distance(1:best price, 2: 2nd best)| price

2008/01/28,09:11:28.000,0,1,1.6066
2008/01/28,09:11:28.000,0,2,1.6065
2008/01/28,09:11:28.000,1,1,1.6068
2008/01/28,09:11:28.000,1,2,1.6069

2008/01/28,09:11:29.000,0,1,1.6067
2008/01/28,09:11:29.000,0,2,1.6066

2008/01/28,09:11:30.000,0,1,1.6065
2008/01/28,09:11:30.000,0,2,1.6064
2008/01/28,09:11:30.000,1,1,1.6066
2008/01/28,09:11:30.000,1,2,1.6067
```

I want to calculate spread=minAsk-maxBid in each block of time. The usual way is to write:

```
mydt[,min(price[side==1]) - max(price[side==0]),by=datetime]
```

However, data has been summarized by this rule: If there is no change in one side, there will be no record in the data. That means comparing block 1 and block 2, there was no change in this part and no record:

```
2008/01/28,09:11:28.000,1,1,1.6068
2008/01/28,09:11:28.000,1,2,1.6069
```

I want to go block by block to calculate some variables(spread, or weighted average price), however sometimes I need information from previous block(because of this rule). How can I do that?

Comment: Maybe `roll=TRUE`. See `?data.table` and search this tag for `roll`. Do the summary first, then roll or fill forward. Maybe `?CJ` too.